# java Audio file location

Tags: java, eclipse, file, audio, stream

I am working on a game in Java and I have a class that reads an audio file as InputStream and then plays that file through AudioPlayer.

I keep getting a file not found exception.

I have tried placing the audio files in many different locations, and nothing has worked.

This is my class code:

```
public void play(String string,int sleep) throws IOException 
{
    //this part does not recognize file
    try {
        //System.out.println(System.getProperty());

        AS = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream(string));
        AD = AS.getData();
        loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(AD);
    }
    catch(IOException error){
        System.out.print(string +" file not found");
    }
    AP.start(loop);     
}
```

I pass a string like ("audio/beginning.wav")

Comment: If the file exists at the specified position, do you have the right rights?
And can you show/describe your project structure?

Comment: The path to the audio file should be relative to the base directory of your source code. For example if the `audio` directory is next to a `src` directory that contains your main method, your string should be "../audio/beginning.wav". It is hard do know what to pass without knowing the structure of your project.

Comment: it is structured "project/src/game/main method" and audio folder is in "project/audio"

Comment: Are you running from the IDE? Try to print the absolute path to debug it, as explained in my answer.

Comment: I am using eclipse. The absolute path goes to the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a path that is relative to the working directory defined when your program runs.

If you are running the program from Eclipse, by default it's the root directory of your program (top-level folder of the program). So normally placing the file in `program_folder/audio/beginning.wav` should work.

However, the working directory can be changed in the **Run Configuration** that you are using in Eclipse to run the program: go to the tab `Arguments`, and you'll find `Working directory`.

To debug the problem, check the output of the following:

```
System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutePath());
```

Another option is to use the absolute path of the file.

Comment: The absolute path gives me the root of the project. I try placing the file there and it still does not recognize it. I have another folder for images in the root that is working just fine. I tried placing the audio in there, still not working.

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace? Also, inside `play()`, try to print `System.out.println(new File(string).getAbsolutePath());` and check that it's what you expect. If you are on Windows, make sure that it's real extension is not hidden.

Comment: java.io.IOException: could not create AudioData object
 at sun.audio.AudioStream.getData(Unknown Source)
 at audio.Audio.play(Audio.java:32)

Comment: C:\Users\lettuce\eclipse-workspace\jajaGui\AudioFiles\beginning.wav
this is the path

Comment: So is the file located in that path? Did you check if it has an hidden extension? Try to print `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(new File("AudioFiles").list()));` and see if the file appears as expected.

Comment: yup, it appears exactly as beginning.wav when printed.